# Implementing Hierholzer's algorithm for a general-purpose graph in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have a **node**(basically the graph **vertex**) *templated* class like this:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
   public:
      T Data;
      Node<T>* Parent;
      vector<Node<T>*> Children;
};
```

and then I have a templated graph class that encapsulates the root of the graph and I have a method the is supposed to generate an Eulerian Path(after it has checked if the conditions for the existence of an Eulerian Path are satisfied):

```
template<class T>
class Graph
{
   public:
      Node<T>* Root;

      vector<Node<T>*> GetEulerianPath() const;
      bool HasEulerianPath() const;
};
```

**HasEulerianPath()** just traverses the **node**(**vertex**) hierarchy and counts the amount of vertices that have an odd degree.If they are no more than two, it returns true.

Now the problem is - I'm not exactly quite sure how do implement the algorithm.Any tips?Should I just extract the entire hierarchy in a **vector** and iterate trough that or do I use some recursive method of **Node**?The [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm) suggest using a **linked list**...or maybe I should just generate an new smaller singledirectional **Graph** as an output for the **GetEulerianPath()** method?I'm confused at how to proceed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have structured your `Node` class basically forms a doubly-linked list that is contained in a `vector`.  There are a few issues (mathematically) that you appear to have:

A given "child" can have more than 1 "parent".  In fact, if there are 2 "child" nodes, there would *have* to be 2 "parent" nodes in order for this to be an Eulerian cycle.  You may want to redefine `Node` as follows:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
   public:
      T Data;
      list<shared_ptr<Node<T>>> Connections;
};
```

Which will allow you to change your `Graph` to:

```
template<class T>
class Graph
{
   public:
      shared_ptr<Node<T>> Start; // name change just to convey that there isn't a "root" node in an Eulerian cycle

      list<shared_ptr<Node<T>>> GetEulerianPath() const;
      bool HasEulerianPath() const;
};
```

This way, implementing Hierholzer's Algorithm is simply a matter of traversing the `Connections` for each node.

Comment: ok I understand now that it won't work out the original way.I mean I made it with children and parent, cause it was meant for a 3d scene graph where each object's spatial properties are dependent on the parent's one and it was also performance-sensitive, so that's why I used vector instead of list.Guess I'll have to make 2 types of graphs or something.

Comment: Since you are dealing with pointers, you can probably get away with using `vector`s instead of `list`s.  You will take a performance hit every time the vector needs to grow (though, unless your graph is substantially large, I doubt it would be noticeable).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your graph first. But definitely not to a std::vector.

For each node you need to be able to quickly get an unused edge (put them all in a linked list and remove when used).

Therefor each node should have a linked list of children not a std::vector.

Next, you need to be able to find nodes which have unused edges, you can just collect those in a linked list while traversing. You also need to build a linked list with your path while traversing, the list of unused edges should refer to this list so you can change the path in O(1).

(The `Node<T>* Parent;` in your code seems odd for a general graph.)